# a.e. convergence on $[0,1]^2$ of a convergent sequence in $L^2\bigl([0,1],H\bigr)$ where $H=L^2[0,1]$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

The question is as in the title.

Let $H=L^2[0,1]$ be the Hilbert space of real-valued $L^2$ functions on the unit interval $[0,1]$.

Then, consider the space $L^2\bigl([0,1],H\bigr)$ whose elements are mappings from $[0,1]$ into $H$ and square integrable with respect to the norm of $H$.

Then, it seems obvious that $L^2\bigl([0,1],H\bigr) \simeq L^2\bigl([0,1]^2\bigr)$.

However, if a sequence $(f_n) \subset L^2\bigl([0,1],H\bigr)$ converges, it has a subsequence that converges a.e. on $[0,1]$ with values in $H$.

On the other hand, convergence in $H$ itself implies another a.e. convergence of a subsequence on $[0,1]$.

Thus, my question is that:

Does there always exist a subsequence of $(f_n )$ which converges a.e. as real-valued functions on $[0,1]^2$?

It seems more subtle than expected..Could anyone please clarify?